# cannot get react to render latest property value

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a render function calling another function:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.renderTableArea() }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

that function is returning a div with a property value:

```
renderTableArea () {
    const {documents} = this.props;

    console.log('documents.length: ', documents.length)
    if (documents.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>This project has no documents yet alex.</div>
      )
    }
  }
```

documents is loaded from the server by redux:

```
function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    projectId: ownProps.projectId,
    documents: state.projectsStore.documents
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchDocuments
})(ProjectDocuments);
```

In the console documents.length shows up 4 times having value 0 the first 2 times and 8 the last 2 times. I expect the div saying that there are no documents to not be rendered in the end because documents.length is not 0 in the end, yet that div is rendered.

I don't understand why that div gets rendered when documents.length ends up being non zero.

Comment: your code seems right, you need to debug and check

Comment: I've been trying to debug it. I took debugger; out before posting the code. I've got console.log in there to. That's how I know for sure that the value is not zero when the page finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your problem statment is that you want to show "This project has no documents yet alex" when document. length is zero and some valid jsx when document.length !== 0. So i can see in your code you haven't returned any thing in the end when document.length !== 0. You can modify your code like this

```
renderTableArea () {
    const {documents} = this.props;

    console.log('documents.length: ', documents.length)
    if (documents.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>This project has no documents yet alex.</div>
      )
    } else if (documents.length !== 0) {
     return (
     <div>
       //some jsx for your document
       {document}
     </div>
     )
}
  }
```

Comment: That does not work. It appears to be failing to re-render. It renders based on the first value it gets which is zero. Later when the value is updated it does not re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Another component was zeroing that property. I don't know how. I'm working around it by copying the property to a variable and passing that to a different property name on the offending component.